# Inaccurate SVG rendering in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg

My SVG image is pixel perfect, and all browsers render it OK, except Firefox.

**Example 1 (Bootstrap markup):**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdVxJo

There are just two rectangles in Bootstrap columns. All the rectangles has pixel-aligned borders and border width=2px but Firefox adds antialiasing.

I guess it depends on area height, but I do not know why. There is an example with one rectangle without any CSS.

**Example 2 (clean HTML):**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OoKxEd

```
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="396" height="100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="396" height="100" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
  </svg>
</body>
```

You maybe need to change height of your render area on CodePen to reproduce the bug.

---

Anybody knows if it is possible to force Firefox to draw lines correctly?

Comment: if you don't want antialiasing, turn it off via shape-rendering: crispEdges but see https://www.cairographics.org/FAQ/#sharp_lines for why you get antialiasing in the first place.

Comment: Maybe just FireFox draws lines correctly. Please add  svg{overflow:visible} and check again.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I tried 
     <svg shape-rendering="crispEdges" ...
and looks like it works! Big thanks!

Comment: ... but my colleague noticed than this breaks smooth lines like rounded rectangles' corners. Will try to make another sample.

Comment: In that case you'll need to read the cairo FAQ